# Extracting multiple values in different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset

```
ID   col1    col2               year
1     A     111,222,3334       2010
2     B     344, 111          2010
3     C      121,123          2011
```

I wanna rearrange the dataset in the following way

```
ID   col1   col2            year
1     A     111            2010
1     A     222            2010
1     A     3334            2010
2     B     344            2010
2     B     111            2010
3     C     121            2011
3     C     123            2011
```

I can do it using the following code.

```
a = df.COMP_MONITOR_TYPE_CODE.str[:3]
df['col2'] = np.where(a == 111, 111)
```

Since, I have a very long data, its would be time consuming to do it one by one. Is there any other way to do it

Comment: Can you provide the code to create your initial dataset, so we have a test example to work with more easily.

Comment: Here you go @Kraigolas, I don't know why OP didn't give it... `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':range(3), 'col1':list('ABC'), 'col2':['111,222,3334','344,111','121,123'],'year':[2010,2010,2011]})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html?highlight=split#pandas.Series.str.split) + [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df.assign(col2 = df.col2.str.split(',')).explode('col2')

#   ID col1  col2  year
#0   1    A   111  2010
#0   1    A   222  2010
#0   1    A  3334  2010
#1   2    B   344  2010
#1   2    B   111  2010
#2   3    C   121  2011
#2   3    C   123  2011
```